# Jupyter notebook not opening in VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

While setting up my new system, I am trying to run my notebook file on VS Code but as soon as I open VS Code it give me this error

```
Failed to detect Jupyter Notebook. Please use 'Select Jupyter Notebook' command
```

in the output:

```
Unable to determine version of Jupyter, Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 6, in <module>
    from notebook.notebookapp import main
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 46, in <module>
    from zmq.eventloop import ioloop
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\__init__.py", line 47, in <module>
    from zmq import backend
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    reraise(*exc_info)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\utils\sixcerpt.py", line 34, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    _ns = select_backend(first)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\select.py", line 27, in select_backend
    mod = __import__(name, fromlist=public_api)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import (constants, error, message, context,
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I have installed all the plugins which were necessary, ran various commands, I also updated the notebook.
`conda install notebook`

I am using:
anaconda 3
vs code 1.26.1
windows 10
I cant start new notebooks or use an existing one either.
Please help, and let me know if any more information is required.

Answer (score 1):

1. Check the required extensions installed in vscode.
2. install jupyter and ipython packages in your python venv using pip:

   ```
    pip install jupyter
    pip install ipython
   ```
3. If its still not working try to change the python kernal in the top right corner of ipynb notebook.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to running `jupyter` without first activating the environment for Python 3.7. This was [fixed](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/3341) in the 2018.12.0 release of the extension.

Answer (score 0):

When it fails with this response you can uninstall `conda` and `jupyter` and install python from VS Code and then update. Don't necessarily install `conda` and `jupyter`.